# Iterate through files from pyspark in databricks from DBFS location in Community Edition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to iterate through the files available in the DBFS location in Databricks.
But it's throwing an error saying 
'org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist:'
Here's the code which I tried:

```
import os
from pyspark.sql.types import *
fileDirectory = '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/'
for fname in os.listdir(fileDirectory):
    df_app = sqlContext.read.format("csv").\
        option("header", "true"). \`enter code here`
        load(fileDirectory + fname)
```

And the error is

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: dbfs:/dbfs/FileStore/tables/Dept_data.csv;

Can you please help with this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

When reading files in Databricks using the DataFrameReaders (ie: `spark.read...`), the paths are read directly from DBFS, where the FileStore tables directory is, in fact: `dbfs:/FileStore/tables/`. The point is that, using the Python os library, the DBFS is another path folder (and that is why you can access it using /dbfs/FileStore/tables). So, using something like this should work fine:

```
import os
from pyspark.sql.types import *
fileDirectory = '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/'
dir = '/FileStore/tables/'
for fname in os.listdir(fileDirectory):
    df_app = sqlContext.read.format("json").option("header", "true").load(dir + fname)
```

In addition, you can double check the dbutils commands (https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#dbutilsfsls-command) that can help you to manipulate the DBFS directly (without dealing with dbfs inner implementation).
Hope this helps